# Ways to fill n x n zero matrix with 1 and -1 so that there can only be one 1 and -1 per row and column and the sum of each row and column is 0

Tags: algorithm, matrix, permutation

I'm looking for a F(n^3) technique to find all possible ways to fill n x n matrix with following rules: There can only be one -1 and one 1 on each row and column. The sum of every row and column has to be 0. N <= 500. The input might already have 1's and -1's placed in it. All the other entries of the matrix are 0s.

I've tried it with backtracking but it's too slow due to possible size of the input.
The solution should be presented mod 10^9 - 7

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there should be about (n!)^2 ways to do that, so it will take quite some time.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that the solution should be presented mod 10^9 - 7

Comment: If this is a programming contest, please provide a link to it.

Answer (score 0):

While typing this answer I forgot about "F(n^3)" part. Maybe extracting "the numbers" (see below) from input requires n^3 algorithm.

Main thing to note here is that you are not supposed to produce all the possible filled matrices. The output is just one number. So if you can find a proper equation then that would be your "algorithm".

Another thing to note is that your input is not relevant in terms of all positions of those non-empty cells. All that matters is these nine numbers:

- number of solo 1's (that don't have a paired -1 in neither row nor column),
- number of solo -1's,
- number of solo row pairs (where neither 1 nor -1 are paired in column)
- number of solo column pairs (same as previous but transposed)
- number of empty rows
- number of empty columns
- number of paired triplets that miss a 1 to make a paired quadruplet
- number of paired triplets that miss a -1 to make a paired quadruplet
- number of paired quadruplets

Here are those seven cases in conceptual matrix form, which won't make sense if you didn't understand them in written form:

```
1 0  | -1 0 | 1 -1 |  1 0 | 0 0 | 0 |  1 -1 | -1 1 |  1 -1
0    |  0   | 0  0 | -1 0 |     | 0 | -1  0 |  1 0 | -1  1
```

You have to extract first eight numbers of those nine from your input, and that's already a nice piece of work. The last one is not as important, because that quadruplet is already filled and "unmergeable".

You also have to figure out how to use the eight numbers. You basically have to figure out which of those conceptual matrix fragments can be "merged" together to make a full matrix fragment (without spaces), then find the number of ways those fragments can be populated with remaining 1's and -1's, and multiply all those numbers.

Last part is modulo operation, but that part is easy. Make sure you have only multiplications ahead of you, and after every multiplication apply modulo operation. Largest product can be 99999993*500 = 49999996500, which is larger than maximum 32-bit integer, but not larger than maximum 64-bit integer. So the easiest thing to do here is to have all operations in 64-bit arithmetic.

EDIT: I just realized this answer is not entirely complete or even correct. I thought matrix fragments can be merged in a simple and straightforward ways, only in pairs, but there could be endless combinations of long streaks of merges. (many solo 1's can be merged together, not just two). So there is not a simple equation in the end. Maybe you can still use the the concept of the answer, but just with more coding.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if we have a -1 and 1 on every column and on every row and there are 2n of them, we are satisfying all the conditions.

- Find all indexes where there is a 1. Let´s call the amount x.
- We need to place (n - x) 1. How many ways there are of doing that? Let´s imagine for a bit that there are no -1s initially placed. Let´s pick the first column without a 1. We need to place a 1 there. We can place it in (n - x) possible positions, as we can´t place it in certain rows where there are already 1s. Let´s pick the second column without a 1. We can place it in (n - x - 1) possible positions, as we have 1 less row we can use from the first one.
- Generalizing that idea, we conclude that we have (n - x ) * (n - x - 1 ) * (n - x - 2) ... * (1). This is, (n - x)!
- Now let´s condider what happens if we have -1s initially placed. The problem with that formula is we are not considering that given a column, we can´t place it on a cell where we already have a -1. So depending on the column, we have 1 less cell we can place a 1 on when that column has a -1. So we would need to change that formula to (n - x - f(col)) * (n - x - 1 - f(col)) * ... being f(col) = 1 when there is a -1 on that column and 0 when not. This works until the last formula, where we get * (1 - f(x)). Problem is on the last column, as we already placed 1s on all the others, there is only 1 option left to place a 1 to, but if that place is the one where we have a -1, we are counting wrong. This is not a problem on the other columns, as we will always have at least 1 empty cell left to use.
- So in the case where the last column that needs a 1 has a -1 already placed, we can´t make that place be the last option left. This means we need to place a 1 on that row by any of the previous columns. If there was a 1 initially placed on that row, we have nothing to worry about.
- To count this, we can do something like this (need to add memoization):

  ```
  func count (idx, x, bool alreadyPlaced):
      if idx == last:
          return alreadyPlaced        
      if alreadyPlaced:
          return (n - x - f(idx)) * count(idx + 1, x + 1, alreadyPlaced)
      else:
          return (n - x - f(idx) - 1) * count(idx + 1, x + 1, false) + count(idx + 1, x + 1, true)
  ```
- With this we know the amount of ways we have of placing 1s on the grid. Now all that is left is to count the amount of ways of placing -1s and multiply these 2.

  Will leave the rest as an exercise, but let me know if you can´t figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I'll look into it today and let you know if I manage to solve it.

Comment: I'm having some problems with taking the already placed 1s into account when counting the -1s. For example if I put the -1 on the first row like this:
`
1|-1|0|0|0 \n
0| 1|0|0|0
`
there is 4 possible ways of placing the -1 on the 2nd row whereas if I place the -1 on the first row like this:
`
1|0|-1|0|0\n
0| 1|0|0|0
`
there is only three ways to put the -1 on the 2nd column.

Comment: are there then 1*4 + 3*3 possible ways of doing that?

Comment: @dannasman good observation. That is a problem I have not considered on counting 1s too. If you have the link to the problem I can try to solve it myself to be sure I am handling correctly all cases

Comment: It's not in English but here is the example input and answer:
`5 \n
0 0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 1 -1 0 \n
0 0 0 0 0 \n
-1 0 0 0 0 \n
0 0 0 0-1 0 \n
\n
output: 16`
First input is n, then the matrix is inserted row by row and the output should be the answer mod (10^9 - 7). I have managed to make a script that works until approx n = 10 put is too slow for the bigger matrix sizes. Here are some other values to help:.
5x5 matrix filled with zeroes only =  5280, number of ways 1s can be placed = 120, number of -1s that can be placed after 1s are placed: 44

Comment: sorry for the bad formatting the '\n' signs are not in the output they are there just to help you understand where the new line of input starts

Comment: Heres also for 3x3 because the numbers are a bit smaller: 
3x3 matrix filled with zeroes only = 12, number of ways 1s can be placed = 6, number of -1s that can be placed after 1s are placed: 2

Comment: Well, already understood problem from you, just want to be able to test if solution is correct. Probably won´t happen soon though, busy this week

Comment: @dannasman can't solve it, maybe try asking on combinatorics stack exchange?

Comment: Just posted the question there. Will let you know of I manage to find a solution.